# $projection & $sum not working as expected in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here are all the details.

**Note:** I am mentioning only the required sample fields

### Collection 1: orders

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e3eb2846cfe9912ece77732"),
    "isApproved": NO,
    "orderCreatedforDate": ISODate("2020-02-15T18:30:00Z"),
    "vendorOrder": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e3cfb1f3f6d3816a4410d97"),
        "publicationName": "Times of India",
        "productCode": "TCE1",
        "tradeCopies": 40
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e3cfb1f3f6d3816a4410d96"),
        "publicationName": "Economic Times",
        "productCode": "ECE1",
        "tradeCopies": 21
      }
    ],
    "frequency": "SA",
    "vendorId": ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    "dealerId": ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),

}
```

there are multiple documents in this collection but we require document for tomorrow's date i.e :`"orderCreatedforDate" : ISODate("2020-02-14T18:30:00Z")` and there can be other documents with different vendorId's or dealerId's

### Collection 2: publications

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"),
    "publicationName": "Times Of India",
    "productCode": "ECE1",
    "frequency": "SA",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "coverPrice": 4,

  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"),
    "publicationName": "Times Of India",
    "productCode": "TCE1",
    "frequency": "SA",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "coverPrice": 5.5,

}
```

this is one of the sample document,there are other documents with different frequency like "MO","TU" etc... and with different cities. 
I need documents for tomorrow i.e "SA" & city `Chennai` so that I can fetch (coverPrice + productCode + city)

### Collection 3: margins

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e4281e7fec2e01a4c60b406"),
    "dealerId": ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    "vendorId": ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    "productCode": "ECE1",
    "frequency": "SA",
    "discount": 0,

  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e4281e7fec2e01a4c60b406"),
    "dealerId": ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    "vendorId": ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    "productCode": "TCE1",
    "frequency": "SA",
    "discount": 26,

}
```

The "discount" in margin collection is in %age [for e.g- "discount":26 is 26%].

Now discount is [productCode, vendorId & city] dependent *if I have an order with a different  `"vendorId":ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4cc007b")` the discount may be different for this vendor i need to keep this in consideration.*

This is what I have been able to achieve so far with this query

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "dealerId": ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
      "vendorId": ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
      "orderCreatedforDate": ISODate("2020-02-15T18:30:00Z"),

    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$vendorOrder"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$vendorOrder"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "publications",
      let: {
        productCode: "$productCode"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            frequency: "SA",
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$productCode",
                "$$productCode"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "publications"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$publications"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "margins",
      let: {
        productCode: "$productCode"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            frequency: "SA",
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$productCode",
                "$$productCode"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "margins"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$margins"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "productCode": "$productCode",
        "date": "$orderCreatedforDate",
        "coverPrice": "$publications.coverPrice",
        "discount": "$margins.discount",
        "tradeCopies": "$tradeCopies",
        "dealerId": "$orders.dealerId"
      },
      "tradeCopies": {
        "$sum": "$tradeCopies"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "dealerId": "$vendorOrder.dealerId",
      "tradeCopies": 1,
      "billOfTheDay": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$tradeCopies",
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$_id.coverPrice",
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  "$_id.coverPrice",
                  {
                    "$divide": [
                      "$_id.discount",
                      100
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "totalBill": {
        "$sum": [
          "billOfTheDay"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The output of this query is:

```
{
    "_id": {
      "productCode": "ECE1",
      "coverPrice": 4,
      "discount": 0,
      "tradeCopies": 67
    },
    "tradeCopies": 67,
    "billOfTheDay": 268,
    "totalBill": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "productCode": "TCE1",
      "coverPrice": 4,
      "discount": 38,
      "tradeCopies": 30
    },
    "tradeCopies": 30,
    "billOfTheDay": 74.4,
    "totalBill": 0
}
```

I have been able to get the bill of individual tradeCopies as it can be seen in my output TCE1's bill of the day:74.4 & ECE1's bill of the day:268.

I want their total i.e [ TCE1+ECE1 : 74.4,268], but this query doesn't seem to be good. Now I want to achieve the total amount of all the tradeCopies after their calculation with respect to their [productCode,coverPrice,discount(vendorId dependent)]
another problem is calculating outstanding :

### Collection 4: payments

```
{

     "date" : ISODate("2020-02-15T18:30:00Z"),
     "dealerId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
     "vendorId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
     "receivables" : 120,
},
{

     "date" : ISODate("2020-02-13T18:30:00Z"),
     "dealerId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
     "vendorId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
     "receivables" : 110,
}
```

I need to calculate the total receivables then need to calculate the outstanding.

This the output which is expected

```
invoice: {
    vendorId: ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    dealerId: ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    billOfTheDay:"342.4"
    recievables: "120"   //latest amount received for the day
    outstanding:"112.4   //"total receivable - bill of the day
}
```

Moreover is it possible to save all this in a new collection for payment history reference, I want to save these fields into paymenthistory collection

```
{
    productCode,
    vendorId,
    dealerId,
    receivables,
    effectivePrice:(tradeCopies*(coverPrice-(coverPrice*discount%))),
    date, 
    billOfTheDay, 
    totalBillOfTheday
}
```

If this can't be saved into a new collection atleast I am able to calculate outstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been able to get the bill of individual tradeCopies as it can be seen in my output TCE1's bill of the day:74.4 & ECE1's bill of the day:268.  I want their total i.e [ TCE1+ECE1 : 74.4,268], but this query doesn't seem to be good.

You can achieve this by adding an extra $group stage to your pipeline.  If you group by `null`, the $group stage calculates accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalBill: {
            $sum: "$billOfTheDay"
        }
    }
}
```

So now your pipeline will look like the following:

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: '$vendorOrder'
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: '$vendorOrder'
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'publications',
  'let': {
    productCode: '$productCode'
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        frequency: 'SA',
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            '$productCode',
            '$$productCode'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'publications'
}}, {$unwind: '$publications'}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'margins',
  'let': {
    productCode: '$productCode'
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        frequency: 'SA',
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            '$productCode',
            '$$productCode'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'margins'
}}, {$unwind: '$margins'}, {$group: {
  _id: {
    productCode: '$productCode',
    date: '$orderCreatedforDate',
    coverPrice: '$publications.coverPrice',
    discount: '$margins.discount',
    tradeCopies: '$tradeCopies',
    dealerId: '$orders.dealerId'
  },
  tradeCopies: {
    $sum: '$tradeCopies'
  }
}}, {$project: {
  dealerId: '$vendorOrder.dealerId',
  tradeCopies: 1,
  billOfTheDay: {
    $multiply: [
      '$tradeCopies',
      {
        $subtract: [
          '$_id.coverPrice',
          {
            $multiply: [
              '$_id.coverPrice',
              {
                $divide: [
                  '$_id.discount',
                  100
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  totalBill: {
    $sum: [
      'billOfTheDay'
    ]
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
        totalBill: {
            $sum: "$billOfTheDay"
        }
}}]
```

> Moreover is it possible to save all this in a new collection for payment history reference, I want to save these fields into paymenthistory collection

Yes, you can use $out to take the results of the aggregation pipeline and save them to a collection. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html

I didn't follow your other questions inside of your original question.  If you still have questions, please add more details and ask again.

Comment: i have tried to add extra $group stage before projection, after projection but it is not working and yes you are right i tried bot $out and $merge but they are saving whatever $projection stage is returning and i am not able to get all the required fields for the new collection , moreover $out just replaces the values whenever i run the query but i want to save the records instead and $merge just keeps creating new documents, can you edit my query to calculate totalBill and outstanding though my approach was to save the totalbill of the day in new collection than calculate the outstanding

Comment: I updated my answer above to indicate the $group stage should go at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: "i tried bot $out and $merge but they are saving whatever $projection stage is returning and i am not able to get all the required fields for the new collection"

Yes, you will need to include whatever fields you want included in the final output at each stage of the pipeline.

Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#comparison-with-merge to determine if $out or $merge is a better approach for your use case.

Comment: @-Lauren thanks to your suggestion later on i was able to get the totalBill but apart from totalBill nothing is getting projected hence nothing is getting saved in the new collection.

Comment: Gald you were able to get the totalBill working!  You'll need to update each stage of the pipeline to include the data you want to carry through to the next.